# Json Web Token example for Java

Tags: jwt

Is there a sample program in Java of HPW to create header, claim set for JWT (service account ) so that I get the Access token?

The following URL looks close:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount#libraries
But I was looking for any sample program to start with.

Does anyone have any help links?

Answer (score 7):

From http://code.google.com/p/jsontoken/

```
svn checkout http://jsontoken.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ jsontoken-read-only
```

And a fully working example:

https://code.google.com/p/gwdg-java/

Answer (score 5):

JJWT aims to be the easiest to use and understand JWT library for the JVM and Android:

https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt